# R function error, "no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Tags: r

I am trying to use a function to generate a series of KS test's p values. In my case, I wish to choose different first M[i] rows from my aaa dataset and after a few steps process to generate the predict glm regression values dd, and finally compare every two datasets to get a KS test's p values. But my code didn't work well. I attached my code in the following using simulated data:

```
set.seed(1)
aaa <- matrix(runif(8000*950), 8000, 950)
ph = sample(rep(0:1,l=950))
kst <- function(M){
  N = length(M)
  aa = list()
  bb = list()
  cc = list()
  dd = list()
  ee = list()
  p = 0
  for (i in 2:N){
    aa[[i]] = aaa[1:M[i],] ## class(aaa) is matrix 
    bb[[i]] = rbind(ph, aa[[i]])
    cc[[i]] = as.data.frame(t(bb[[i]]))
    dd[[i]] = glm(data = cc[[i]], formula = ph~., family = binomial)
    ee[[i]] = ks.test(predict(dd[[i-1]]), predict(dd[[i]]))
    p[i] = ee[[i]]$p.value
  }
  return(p)
}
kst(M = seq(50,950,by=50))
```

but R said:

```
> kst(M = seq(50,950,by=50))
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

I think my ks.test loop also has error in it, but I did not know how to fix it.
Could anyone help me about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't test without data, but `i in 1:N-1` looks wrong. Try a small example like `1:3-1` and see what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably at `for (i in 1:N-1)`

R interprets `1:N-1` as sequence 1 to N, then subtract 1 from the whole vector.
Try `1:5-1` to see what I mean.

Try `for (i in 1:(N-1))`

Also in this line

```
 ee[[i]] = ks.test(predict(dd[[i]]), predict(dd[[i+1]])) ## this line may also have problem.
```

`dd[[i+1]]` will not be defined yet, as your loop has only filled `dd` to `i`.

Not sure this is what you are trying to do but maybe:

```
  if(i>1L)ee[[i]] = ks.test(predict(dd[[i-1]]), predict(dd[[i]]))
```

That way after you have filled the first entry of `dd` you start testing the current `dd` vs. the previous.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. While, I do not know why did you use if(i >1L)? And after I changed to for (i in 1:(N-1)), then R said,   no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL" . It still did not work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @JINBOZHAO As Chris says, in your `predict` call you have `dd[[i - 1]]`. When `i` is 1, `i - 1` is 0. `dd[[0]]` isn't anything - lists start with 1 not 0. So R is telling you that you can't predict on nothing. Chris suggests a solution: only predict if `i` is greater than 1. In R code, this is translated to `if(i > 1)`.

Comment: @JINBOZHAO I added the `if` statement for the reason @Gregor details.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMcCort, your help is very useful.